# How to use wifi on CentOS 9?

Tags: wireless-networking, centos, wifi-configuration

I installed CentOS 9 Stream on my laptop.

During the installation (while I still was in the installation interface), I was able to connect to internet via Wifi. The wifi interface was up and was connected to my wifi through the interface `wlo1`.

After the installation finished, the internet connection disappeared. In a terminal, I typed `ifconfig` but the wifi interface (`wlo1`) did not appeared. So I tried to activate it via `nmtui`. In the `nmtui` interface, in the "Modify a connection" menu, the wifi appeared as activated and connected to my wifi. However, I cannot see it in the "Activate" menu.

I still don't have internet access. When I go to parameters, the wifi interface doesn't appear.

What can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Install NetworkManager-wifi.
2. Restart NetworkManager service

See this topic:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/408012/how-can-i-find-out-what-plugin-is-missing-in-nmcli

Answer (score 0):

`lspci | grep Network` to determine chipset of device if NOT usb attached.
lsusb if usb attached.

lspci example:
`lspci | grep Network`

> 00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 06)
> 03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6200 (rev 35)
> --- Intel wifi N6200, intel has drivers on their website.

lsusb example:
`lsusb`

> Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
> Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
> Bus 001 Device 009: ID 0bda:c811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
> Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
> Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
> --- Realtek wifi device, good luck, have not found driver yet.

search for driver info for detected device